# How to change tableview cell height according to label text swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

Using a `UITableView` in **Swift**, could someone please help me automatically change the height of the cell based on the label, picture, and description please?

I want to dynamically change the cell size as the label text increases. i have already applied autolayout on the labels.

Comment: can you add image of your tableview cell constraint?

Comment: One thing you will have to do set your labels up like this: `yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0; yourLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping`. Another possibility is to set width constraints on the label, then add text, and then call `yourLabel.sizeToFit()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering you have already applied constraints on the label. And also set your number of lines to 0. And then paste the following code in viewDidLoad method

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: In this case, should the label have the bottomAnchor defined or not?

Answer (score 4):

If the code below doesnt work  in method **viewDidLoad** doesn't work  instead add the code below in method
**ViewWillAppear**

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0// the estimated row height ..the closer the better
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

plus :

1. The constrain should atleast define the width ,top spacing and bottom spacing **not the height constrain**.
2. In attributes  set lines to 0

Answer (score 1):

> For making the cell auto sizeable, you need to do two things:
>
> 1. Bottom space and top space constraints will push the cell size as needed. number of lines of label is 0.
> 2. In your viewDidLoad() method add `self.tblList.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0 self.tblList.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 answer:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Please be sure that the constraints are set